# How does printf write to stdout?

Tags: c, file-handling, io

I've been looking for an answer to this for a couple days, and all of the results I've come up with are about how printf accepts an arbitrary number of arguments.

How does printf write to stdout? What is the most fundamental way to write to a file in C? How do the standard libraries work?

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=printf+filetype%3Ac&ie=UTF-8

Comment: While this is far too vague/broad/unresearched to be effectively answerable, what you might be after is: At some point it's going to have to call platform-specific code, typically system calls into the OS which are going to be different for every OS the language is implemented on. If you want to know how the system calls are implemented, go read a book about operating systems and how they manage file systems.

Answer (score 10):

At the lowest possible level from a *user program* running in some *operating system*, the libc is making [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (or syscalls). These are often a single machine instruction (often `SYSCALL` or `SYSENTER`) which is given some parameters and which switches the [microprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor) to [supervisor mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring#SUPERVISOR-MODE) in a controlled way. Then the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) is processing the parameters and handling the syscall and finally returning to user space.  For Linux, you might read its [Assembly HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Assembly-HOWTO/) and the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) spec.

BTW, you could install Linux and study the source code of some libc. Notice that [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) is quite readable.

Of course syscalls (and the protocol to invoke them) are operating system specific. You could read [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) to get a list of them (for Linux).

`printf` (and `puts`) would ultimately invoke the [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall. For performance reasons, `<stdio.h>` is buffering.

Notice that `printf` is standardized in [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (a programming language standard) but `write` is standardized in the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)  *Portable Operating System Interface* standard (but Microsoft Windows is not POSIX compliant).

Often, `printf` does not call `fputs`, but will use some syscall (like  `write` on Linux). BTW, some implementations (notably the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) thru its `__builtin__snprintf*` builtins known by `/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h` included by `<stdio.h>`) are able to optimize some simple calls to `printf`  into calls to `puts`....

Answer (score 6):

`printf( string, ... )` can be thought of (*1) as internally invoking `vfprintf( stdout, string, va_list )` which in turn can be thought of as internally invoking `fputs( string, stdout )`

The implementation of `fputs( string, stdout )` is operating-system specific.

So, (parts of the) standard libraries are rewritten on an operating system by operating system basis to make use of the native facilities provided by the underlying system in order to accomplish their purpose.

(*1) I say "can be thought of" because whether it does precisely that or something else which is equivalent to that is implementation-specific, and none of our concern.

Comment: Thanks. That answer is helpful, but it also begs more questions. How could fputs be implemented? Is it a call to a function outside C, or is it something that actually *could* be written in C given a certain platform?

Comment: "to make use of the native facilities provided by the underlying system" means that `fputs` is implemented using a call to a function "outside C".  For example, in windows, it invokes the `WriteFile` method of the Win32 API. Which in turn is most probably also written in C, but now we are talking about an entirely different scope of things.  You don't get to write functions of that kind unless you are writing an operating system.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, and it gives me a greater appreciation for the standard library. ;) Cheers!

Comment: i did this a long time ago for a simple graphics app that could basically draw lines, text, and circles/arcs.  there was a concept of points on the 2-dimensional display and a "pen" location that was a point.  you can move the pen to any (x,y) coordinate and draw a line to any other (x,y) coordinate.  for text, the pen was the base line and there was a primitive putchar() like function that transferred pixels of a bitmap for each ASCII character to the display and then moved the pen to the right by an amount equal to the width of the char.  but, like Mike says, it's application specific.

Comment: I don't think `vfprintf` can work in terms of `fputs`, since `printf("%c",0);` is defined as causing a single 0 byte to be sent to standard output, and `fputs` is incapable of sending zero bytes.  I would expect `printf` would use `fwrite` or an equivalent function; personally I wish there were a `vprintf` variant that were defined as accepting a `void*` and a pointer to a function that accepted a `void*`, a `const char*`, and number, and would returned `int`; such a variant could then be used to implement all the other standard forms of `printf`, and many additional forms besides.

Comment: @supercat On GNU libc, you can construct something like that using `fopencookie`. That's still hacky though.